# Angular 4 ngOninit not invoke when routing from on component to another component using Facebook login api

Tags: angular, facebook-graph-api, routes, angular-ngmodel, amazon-cognito

I am using angular 4. when routing from one component to another component ngOninit not invoking. i have tried different methos but no use.

Here is my code:

app-router.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { GetStartedComponent } from './auth/get-started/get-started.component';
import { FbregisterComponent } from './auth/fbregister/fbregister.component';


const routes: Routes = [ 
  { path: 'GetStarted', component: GetStartedComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'Fbregister', component: FbregisterComponent, pathMatch: 'full'}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

getstarted.component.ts:
Here i am using facebook api

```
onfacebooklogin(httpobj,navobj,navthis){
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', (response => {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            FB.login(function () {          
            let accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
            FB.api('/me', 'get', { access_token: accessToken, fields: 'id,name,gender,email,first_name,last_name' }, function(response) {              
                sessionStorage.setItem('fbAccessToken',accessToken);
                if (true) {

                    console.log('You are now logged in.');
                    AWS.config.update({
                        region: CognitoUtil._REGION,
                        credentials: new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
                            IdentityPoolId: CognitoUtil._IDENTITY_POOL_ID,
                            Logins: {
                                'graph.facebook.com': accessToken,                                       
                            },                          
                        })     
                    });
                    console.log("accesstoken", accessToken);
                    navthis.zone.run(() => {
                        httpobj.get('/api.json' + response.id)
                        .map( res => {
                            if (res) {
                                if (res.status === 200) {
                                    sessionStorage.setItem('faceBookLoginValid',accessToken);                              
                                    navobj.navigate(['/']);    // Here i am routing the component                            
                                } 
                            }
                        }) 
                        .catch(() =>{                      
                            sessionStorage.setItem('FacebookDetails', JSON.stringify(response));                                                        
                            navobj.navigate(['/facebookRegistration']); // Here i am routing the component
                        })
                        .subscribe((data) => {},
                        err => {});  
                    });   
                } else {
                    //console.log('There was a problem logging you in.');
                }

            });
        });
        } else {
            console.log("not connected");
        }

    }));
  }
```

fbregister.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response, RequestOptions  } from "@angular/http";
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params, ParamMap,  } from '@angular/router';    

@Component({
  selector: 'app-fbregister',
  templateUrl: './fbregister.component.html',
  providers:[RegistrationFacebookUser1],
  styleUrls: ['./fbregister.component.css'],

})
export class FbregisterComponent implements OnInit {    
  public name1: string;
  public lname1: string;
  public email1: string;     
  constructor(public http:Http, private sharedService: SharedService, public registrationUser:RegistrationFacebookUser1, 
    public registrationService:RegistrationService, public router:Router, private zone:NgZone) {}

  public ngOnInit() {        
    console.log("test praba");
    var retrievedObject = sessionStorage.getItem('FacebookDetails');    
    var parsedObject = JSON.parse(retrievedObject);    
    console.log('tett',parsedObject);  
    this.email1 =  parsedObject.email; 
    this.name1 =  'test1111';        
    console.log('test',this.email1);  

  }

}
```

HTML

```
 {{name1}}<br>{{email1}}
```

While routing to this component ngOnint called i have tested using console but its not printed. but when i refresh the page it will load the ngOninit.

I am using sessionstorage to retrive datas. i need to display retrived datas to html while routing from one component to another component.

Comment: What are your routes? Are you sure you're routing to a different component, or is it only a different route parameter with the same route and therefore same component? `ngOnInit` is called when you navigate to a different route, but not when only a route parameter changes.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer i am using different routers only i am routing from getstarted component to fbregister component... this are my routes --> from  { path: 'GetStarted', component: GetStartedComponent, pathMatch: 'full' }, to { path: 'Fbregister', component: FbregisterComponent, pathMatch: 'full'}

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code there. Code in comments is unreadable. What does "different routers" mean exactly? (different routes?)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer i have added my router code also the two components

Comment: this is strange it should , the only things that bothers me is why path match for all routes can you remove and try

Comment: @RahulSingh i have removed path match also no use. still getting same issue

Comment: Is it never logged or just not at routing?

Comment: @Vega its logged when full page is refreshing after routing. its not logged when routing...

Comment: The component has been initialised, so ngOnInit already run but not rendered. why do you want it to be run? to set new values? Do the two components need to share data?

Comment: @Vega : Yes exactly

Answer (score 0):

From the code you've shown, you're not navigating at all, that's why the OnInit is not executed.

```
navobj.navigate(['/']);    // Here i am routing the component
```

You try to navigate to "/" here, but you don't have that route defined at all. So the router does nothing, no navigation at all. Try navigating explicitly to your Facebook route there.